Is there a way to dynamically load UserAnnotation() or the custom closure version UserAnnotation(){}?
Using the standard Map() initialiser I want to show either th UserAnnotation() view or create my own view using the UserAnnotation(){} closure.
I need this to be triggered by a boolean.
I have created an example view and the if/else statement works fine if I set it to a value where it's declared but when I toggle it in runtime/preview it still uses the declared value.
I have a print statement just before the if/else and it seems to just ignore this?
I've tried it with a local declared var Bool, an $State, an @AppStorage and in this example a @Published but I still cannot get it to use the toggled value I have in a button to test. It always uses the declared initial value.
Appreciate any insights or workaround to achieve this .. thanks
import SwiftUI
import MapKit

final class TestingViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var showArrowToTarget = false  // changing here is the only place that works
}
struct TestingView: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = TestingViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        Map(initialPosition: .userLocation(fallback: .automatic)){
            let _ = print("isShowingCustom = \( viewModel.showArrowToTarget)")
            if viewModel.showArrowToTarget {
                UserAnnotation(){
                    Text("showArrowToTarget").font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.title/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    let _ = print("..CustomUserAnnotation isShowingCustom = \( viewModel.showArrowToTarget)")
                }
            } else {
                UserAnnotation()
                let _ = print("..UserAnnotation isShowingCustom =  \( viewModel.showArrowToTarget)")
            }
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .top){
            // Press this to toggle true/false works but refers to initialised value in the if/else ???
            Button("Toggle showArrowToTarget showArrowToTarget= \(viewModel.showArrowToTarget)"){
                viewModel.showArrowToTarget.toggle()
                let _ = print("..toggle to  \( viewModel.showArrowToTarget)")
            }
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    TabView{
        TestingView()
    }
}


your code seems to work for me, I can see the different prints when tapping the button, tested on real devices not the preview with the odd TabView.

I just tested on my iPhone11 and still doesn't switch - I start with set to false and get this ..  Stays with non custom..
...toggle to false
isShowingCustom = false
• UserAnnotation isShowingCustom = false
..toggle to true
isShowingCustom = true
..toggle to false
isShowingCustom = false
• UserAnnotation isShowingCustom = false
Then I set to true and it gets stuck on the Custom one regarless of the toggle

set to true.....CustomUserAnnotation isShowingCustom = false ..CustomUserAnnotation isShowingCustom = false ..toggle to  true isShowingCustom = true ..CustomUserAnnotation isShowingCustom = true ..CustomUserAnnotation isShowingCustom = true 

sorry, correction, I can replicate your problem.

I've tried a bunch of ways, but no luck. IMHO, maybe UserAnnotation was attached within Map from the first time it was initialized. It's different than Marker, which can be replaced during Map's lifetime. Thus, there is a workaround to force redrawing the entire Map when viewModel.showArrowToTarget changes.
Notice: This is a totally wasteful and ineffective way, so it would be the last choice.
@State private var mapID = UUID()

...
Map {
    if viewModel.showArrowToTarget {
        UserAnnotation() {
            Text("showArrowToTarget")
                .font(.title)
        }
    } else {
        UserAnnotation()
    }
}
.id(mapID) //<- force here
.safeAreaInset(edge: .top) {
    Button("Toggle showArrowToTarget...") {
        viewModel.showArrowToTarget.toggle()
        mapID = UUID() //<- force here
    }
}


FYI when I reported issues like this to Apple, e.g. about the PhotoPicker not updating between .movies and .photos their suggested fix was to change the id is the same way as this. I think the non-SwiftUI framework teams struggle to design their Views correctly.

Thank you for your helpful information, I hope they will find a solution to deal with such those kinds of issues in the future. @malhal

thanks @son for the .id idea which partially worked but caused some other refresh issues so I ended up with a workaround to just load the custom object with the closure and a call a custom view and then within that view I switch to display a different custom annotation based on the boolean flag. This is more stable with the only downside is I cannot use the default UserAnnotation() view in the custom view but I made my own approximation. thanks

Exactly, I  dived into that approach. The drawback is it will ignore the default behavior/appearance of UserAnnotation. There is always a trade-off somehow. Glad you found a workaround on your own, happy coding!
